# adding uiimageview inside scrollview using auto layout is adding space at top and bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to design iOS screen.I want to design screen showing imageview at top of screen and scrollview having another image view at bottom of screen. I want to design screens for iOS 6 and 6 plus

I have added imageview at top with 400 width and 239 height (image size 750w and 448h).This scroll view should scroll in the app to show full image on screen.

I have added scrollview and then imageview inside scrollview.My image size inside scrollview is 750 width and 1134 height.

I can see width and height of total screen as 400w and 800h.

I want to know

1. What should be size of image inside imageview to have proper aspect ratio.
2. I have created imageview of 400w,605h size. Scrollview is adding some extra space at top and bottom of screen.
   3.What should be constraint for fitting larger image inside scrollview.

Extra space at top and bottom of scrollview is big problem for me

Comment: please share your screen..

Answer (score 0):

Add a contentMode to your imageView for example:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: I tried using aspect fill in storyboard but it is stretching image a bit.